# Send copy of the order to email in virtuemart

Tags: email, joomla3.0, virtuemart, joomla-module

I tried this for a hours, i need to send the copy of order to some other users in save in admin panel with comma split. is this possible.i don't want to touch the core file. please help me. thx in adv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you create a group email adress where you send the order mail to and let distribute them to the other email adresses.

Comment: I need to edit the email address in admin panel in virtuemart any other idea.